# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1.ui

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-designer

Скачал,Qt Designer,решил проверить работоспособность окна который я сделал ввожу команду и мне пишет FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1.ui'
(КОМАНДА)
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

```
Form, Window = uic.loadUiType("1.ui")

app = QApplication([])
window = Window()
form = Form()
form.setupUi(window)
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я бы вам посоветовал положить `12.py` и `1.ui` в какую-то папку. И находясь в этой папке в CMD/терминале/консоли набрать `python 12.py` и у вас все получится.

Comment: Спасибо,ну ведь все равно оно должно и таким образом запускаться только не понимаю проблему,еще раз спасибо)

Comment: Проблема в том, что `Нет такого файла или каталога: '1.ui'`, т.е. вам надо указать путь у файлу `1.ui` или положить его рядом с `12.py`